# Running into issues when I create ever lasting publisher in Pika

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, pika

I have a Django website and I want requests coming from it to be always published to RabbitMQ. For that, I'm using Pika `BlockingConnection` and I keep the connection always open to publish website requests using `basic_publish`, but when the connection is stale a bit I get the following exception whenever I publish a new message

```
pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe')
```

This is the code I use to manage my connection

```
class ConnectionManager():
    connection = None

    def get_connection(self):
        if(self.connection and self.connection.is_open):
            return self.connection
        
        params = pika.URLParameters('amqp://guest:guest@rabbit-server1:5672/%2F')
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
        return self.connection

    def get_channel(self, queue_name):

        if(self.channel and 
            self.channel.is_open and
            self.connection.is_open):

            return channel

        self.channel = self.get_connection().channel()
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, durable = True)
        return self.channel
```

And for publishing:

```
publisher = ConnectionManager()

def publish_message(request_message):
    publisher.get_channel("queue").basic_publish(exchange='',
                        routing_key="some_key",
                        body=json.dumps(request_message),
                        properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                            delivery_mode = 2, 
                    ))
```

How can I maintain a forever running connection that serves my purpose?

Comment: RabbitMQ will probably log something useful when you get that exception. What is logged?

Comment: `2020-09-25 13:34:55.019 [error] <0.20681.8> closing AMQP connection <0.20681.8> (127.0.0.1:52240 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s`

This is a the log. Shall I add heartbeat parameter to the connection string and give it a value less than 60s?

Comment: Please do a search using the terms `pika block I/O loop`. Your code is blocking Pika from being able to send heartbeats.

Comment: Thank you. I searched the log but there was nothing referring to `pika block I/O loop`. Also searched for just `block` but no log entry found.

Comment: @LukeBakken Can you please suggest a way to make my connection ever lasting and avoid that broken pipe exception?